# Embed font to JasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

I'm using Mac and Jasper Reports 5.1.0 to generate report. I'm trying to export report with Garamond Font. I'm able to generate report from iReport 5.6.0. From Java Maven application i'm trying to export report as PDF, while running i am getting below error,

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Could not load the following font : pdfFontName : Garamond pdfEncoding : Cp1252 isPdfEmbedded : true
```

My jrxml file font part is,

```
<style name="alternateStyle" isDefault="true" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Garamond" fontSize="10" isStrikeThrough="false" pdfFontName="Garamond" pdfEncoding="Identity-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

I tried encoding formats Cp1252 and Identity-H, but both giving same errors.

Anyone please help me to solve this.

Comment: By giving the full path of the ttf file for the attribute "pdfFontName"i can see the report from the application, but this value needs to be passed from Java file, how can i do that?

Comment: *Do you mean u want to pass the `fontName` from Java code ?* If yes, then you can create `parameter` in JasperReport, using `Expression` set value in JasperReport & pass the value of that parameter from the Java code.

Comment: I want to pass the font file path, I able to pass the value but this parameter value is not accessible as per the DTD. Since Styles will be initiated before parameters were visible.

Comment: What do u mean by *not accessible as per the DTD* ? Which *Styles* need to be initialized b4 parameter initialization ?

Comment: Try setting the value for Font using [`JRProperties.setProperty(java.lang.String key, boolean value)`](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRProperties.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29)

Comment: As per the file http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd Styles should be declared before Parameter

Comment: Got it Solved by using the external style sheet reference. Thank You @007

Comment: I though not passed the value from Parameter, i created a separate file with the font filepath, which is not a dynamic solution but it is easy to change style alone in a separate file.